# Security on MarkLogic Local Host Fail Over

Tags: marklogic

Being a relative newbie to ML, I have a question that probably has an obvious answer, but I'll ask anyway.  We have several ML clusters set up with local disk failover.  However, the way it's set up here is that all members of the group have their security databases set to the security database on the cluster host.  My question is, if the cluster host goes down, what happens to security on the other servers in the cluster?  Should the security database instead be replicated across the cluster servers?

Answer (score 1):

If there is only a primary security Forest on one host, and that host goes down,
the entire cluster is effectively halted until that server comes up.
It is common practice to replicate the security database as well as you "data" databases.
Also depending on your application consider replicating other databases such as Schemas,
Modules etc.  Any non-replicated database will block use of that database if the only host that 
has a forest for it goes down.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the security database should be replicated across the cluster servers.

As you suggest, to do this, you need to create a replica of the security and schema forests.

I recommend using multiple replicas especially since these forests are small and critical for database uptime.

I also recommend creating replicas of the App-Services forest so you'll be able to use the Admin applications that run on ports 8000, 8001, and 8002 when the first host is down.